# Is it possible to create an arch that allows for an app to be downloaded and installed at the same time?

Tags: architecture

In theory, if I wanted to have a developer write some sort of computer architecture/OS, could I have him/her add the capability to download + install something at the *same time*. I'm thinking like something where the file is shredded into pieces, and as parts are being downloaded (the user'd see it as one file), other parts are being installed.

Any ideas? This question is coming from a non-developer, so please be lenient.

Comment: Sounds like Steam to me...

Comment: The current version of MS Office is distributed in exactly this way.  You can even start using it before the entire package is downloaded.

Comment: It depends upon the application and the operating system.

Comment: @BrianSnow Yes I didn't recall that the new Office and Steam were done that way. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could have software deployed in a model where "download" and "install" are synonyms.  This is all possible because one of the most important things for a non-programmer to realize about software.

## A file is a file is a file.

From a system standpoint, there is no real difference between "SinghApp.exe" and "SinghApp.docx".  One has an extension that says it can be ran as a program, while other has an extension that says it can be opened as a Microsoft Word Document... but that's just a name, and the OS itself doesn't care one wit about the contents of either file.

When you distribute software as an installer, you're really distributing a small program written to place certain files in certain locations on the file system, along with performing some small system calls for file association and other tasks.  For programs that depend on the internet to function, it's not uncommon for the "installer" to download most of its bulk during the installation process.

It's not too hard to come up with examples -- MMORPG's do this as a matter of course, and I've seen similar behavior in web browsers from Mozilla or Google and the last Java installer I bothered with.  Even Microsoft got into the game; the new subscription version of office actually had new system calls written for its distribution, which is why you can't use Office 365 on Vista.

---

#### Of course, just because you **can** do something doesn't mean that you **should**.

If you're talking about an internal application to be used by your employees on systems you control, this soft of thing can make administration modestly easier.

Conversely, if you're thinking of doing this for software you'll release into the wild, a stub installer should be clearly labeled as such, and a separate download would be appropriate.  Not every user is going to want you knowing each computer they install the software on, and others won't like the thought of being dependent on your servers for their internal installation process.